# Trying to convert data types in sql tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I am trying to change the data types on an SQL table with around 20m records.  I have done the alter table alter column it took way too long to make any impact. I even recreated the table with the new data types and sizes and tried to export it in.  That game me a paging error.  Please help.

Comment: What types are you converting? varchar > nvarchar, datetime to date, varchar to guid?

Comment: Read this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/82154/46223

Comment: nvarchar -> varchar,  float-> int and float ->decimal

Comment: I am trying the insert select but I am getting paging errors @ 50% completion.  I have changed the file growth to unrestricted for both the .mdf and .ldf files.  The filegroup I am getting the error on is Primary.